# What is a power Delaunay triangulation, and how is it computed?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity, triangulation

What is a **power** Delaunay triangulation? and how would I compute it in n-Dimension?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the [wiki article on the power diagram.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram)

Comment: it does not mention that it is related to Delaunay triangulation or how to compute it for n-Dimension.